# Logout and then immediately login again with one command

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gnome-session

Is it possible to logout the current user and immediately login the same user again with one command in the terminal?

Comment: This sounds like a [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @vidarlo You're kind of right. I encounter a bug on my machine, where Nautilus becomes unresponsive when I eject a USB stick. Logging out and back in again solves the problem. I know that I should file a bug report but at the moment I cannot reproduce the bug consistently.

Comment: Have you tried just killing nautilus? It's not a fix, but it might be a workaround :)

Answer (score 1):

That's kind of a tricky question. It is not possible if you are running the script as the same user. When you log out, you are closing the terminal session, so whatever script or processes that are initialized by the user that is logging out will stop as well, including your script to log you back in. However, if you have another user who is running the script to log you out then log you in again, I suppose that it is feasible, although it is not really advantageous...